# get href content using rel value - getElementsByTagName - php

Tags: php

I have in my page one html like this:

```
<li class=category><a href="#" rel="category name">WHAT I WANT</a></li>
<li class=name><a href="#" rel="name">name</a></li>
<li class=date><a href="#" rel="date">date</a></li>
```

I need to get the `WHAT I WANT` value.

So I tried:

```
$linkss = $d->getElementsByTagName('a');
$cat = $linkss->item(0)->getAttribute('category name');
```

but it is not working... Any ideas why? How can I get just the What I want inside the `href rel category name`?

Comment: Attribute name is `rel`. `category name` is attribute __value__

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute is `rel`, not `category name`; `category name` is the value of the attribute. You need to varify the attribute matches then output the `nodeValue` when you have a match.

```
$linkss = $d->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($linkss as $link) {
   if($link->getAttribute('rel') == 'category name') {
        echo $link->nodeValue;
   }
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/668733

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$linkss = $d->getElementsByTagName('a');
$cat = $linkss->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

or

```
$linkss = $d->getElementsByTagName('a');
$cat = $linkss->item(0)->textContent;
```